# JQuery Deferred result of Function using Ajax

Tags: jquery, deferred

I need to return a value from a function based on the results of an ajax call. My problem is that I can't change the method that gets called (getHtml) because it's from a third party and I can't control that code.

So I need to use the getHtml function to somehow return the result after the ajax call is finished.

I tried a number of things including the following.  But it doesn't work because it is simply return the getOptions immediately.

I can't figure out how to do it with callbacks if I can't control how getHtml is called.

```
    ...

    // I need to use this getHtml function
    getHtml: function() {

        var that = this;

        var id = this.id;

        return this.getOptions(id).then(function(options) {

             // I want to return this from the getHtml function
             // after options have been retrieved via ajax:

             return that.template(options); 
        }

    },


    getOptions: function(id)
    {
        return $.post( 
                  myurl, 
                  {
                    action: '/myaction', 
                    data: {id:id} 
                  } 
        );

     }, 

    ...
```

Comment: You can't do `getHtml().done(function (respdata) {})` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getHtml()` function is asynchronous because it calls a function that calls `$.post()` to get its work done.  As such, `getHtml()` returns BEFORE the result has been obtained.  Thus, it cannot return the result.  There is no magic trick in Javascript to take an asynchronous task and somehow make it synchronous so that you can return the result from `getHtml()`.  You can't.

Instead, you must use an asynchronous mechanism for communicating the return result.  Since you're already using promises and jQuery ajax functions already support promises, that is the logical way to go here.

But, the caller of `getHtml()` will HAVE to change.  Short of switching to synchronous Ajax which is not recommended at all, there is no way to make `getHtml()` return the result directly.

You already have the proper scaffolding.  The caller of `getHtml()` just needs to use the returned promise like this:

```
obj.getHtml().then(function(result) {
    // process result here
});
```

Your only two options here are to stop using any asynchronous operations anywhere in `getHtml()` so it can return the result directly (if you need Ajax in that function, then you would have to switch to synchronous Ajax which is NOT recommended at all) or change the way `getHtml()` is called so it can return the result via some sort of callback (promises is a recommended way).  Those are the two main paths to resolve this.